# How can I compile and include Matlab files in Python under Ubuntu

Tags: python, matlab, dll, matlab-deployment, shared-libraries

I wrote a trajectory planner in Matlab, and I would like to compile as a .dll or .so to include in Python. Is it possible, if yes where and how can I start? I already installed the gcc and g++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm asuming you coded m-Code and not C++-code in MATLAB (because the latter one would be easily convertable to some sort of C++ library): Perhaps try MATLAB-Coder which will help you generate C++ code from your m-Code:
http://www.mathworks.de/products/matlab-coder/?s_cid=global_nav

Perhaps it's what you're looking for :)

Comment: Yeah than have a look at the link. It's the only way I can think of o automatically generate C++ code which you could than compile into a dll file.

Answer (score 1):

Another support tool that might be of interest is [MlabWrap](http://www.scipy.org/MlabWrap).

If access to the MATLAB compilers is a problem, [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) and [Pytave](https://launchpad.net/pytave) may be an alternative that is cheaper than a full rewrite